# JavaScript - Refresh EventHandler

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, handler

I am working on a MVC project where we use a external framework. This external framework seems to handle events on different tags. If i add a `<a>` tag to the cshtml the EventHandler fires just perfect. If I however add the `<a>` tag in the JavaScript it doesn't fire at all.

I can't add the EventHandler direct since I don't know which one it is.

Is there a way where I can re-add the EventHandler to all `<a>` tags ? Even if I don't know the name/method of the Handler ?

Comment: Nope. Deobfuscate the framework and search for "window.addEventListener"

Comment: What _is_ the external framework?